# Android: How to perform zoom on two imageviews in android?

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, android-framelayout

I have two images inside my layout. I need to zoom that image which i touched. We know that Frame can display a single view at a time. So how do i perform zoom on each imageview separately ? My xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
  android:src="@drawable/image1" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"   android:src="@drawable/image2"

  />

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity file :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
private static final String TAG = "Touch";

// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

private ImageView iv1;
private ImageView iv2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    iv1 = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
    iv1.setOnTouchListener(this);


    iv2 = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2));
    iv2.setOnTouchListener(this);



}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageView1:
        zoomImageView(v, event);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView2:
        zoomImageView(v, event);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean zoomImageView(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;


    switch (event.getAction() & 255) 
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
        mode = DRAG;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

    case 6: // second finger lifted

        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
        break;

    case 5: // first and second finger down

        oldDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 5f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (mode == DRAG) 
        { 
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
        } 
        else if (mode == ZOOM) 
        { 
            // pinch zooming
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 5f) 
            {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                // zoom out
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled

}
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
 }
```

Now i'am able zoom only image1 which is on top. How do i get the zoom functionality for  bottom image on touch of image2 ? I should be able to zoom the image on which i touched.   Please help me.

Comment: Hey Rahul do you find any solution???

Comment: sorry anshuman dint get any answer. still trying. If you get any plz infrm me thnks..

Comment: @Tech.Rahul Are you get your solution ,and can you have idea how we can apply pinch zoom in-out for Canvas of `ImageView`.I am looking for answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10482229/596725

Comment: Sorry Rahul, I don't have any idea right now for your problem.

Comment: its ok @Anshuman.. did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LinearLayout** and align them **horizontally** or **vertically** in this way you will have two imageviews which are independent with each other
 then use **gestureimageview** which supports panning zooming and and double tap see link below....

hope this answers your question :D

Click [here](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview)!

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use ZoomageView instead of ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

<com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Add dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'
```

Hope this will help you.